# How do I invoke the animation again when state stays the same

Tags: vue.js, animate.css

I am figuring out how I can re-animate the shake animation on an incorrect answer. Or the flash animation on a correct answer.

I defined 2 booleans as a state for the correct answer and I understand that if I enter the same incorrect answer the incorrect flash stays false. But how do I fix that the shake animations kicks in another time.

I made a fiddle, the correct code is '1234'. When you first fail to enter, the shake animation kicks in. Same is for the correct answer. Only the first time the animations shows.

How can I invoke the animations again when correct or incorrect answers are given.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger animated" 
  v-bind:class="{ 'shake': incorrect }" 
  v-if="incorrect">
  Code is incorrect
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrklein/05sfmuc2/

```
new Vue({
el: "#app",
  data: {
    correct: false,
    incorrect: false,
    code: '1234',
    modelcode: '',
  },
  methods: {
    checkpwd: function(todo){
        if (this.modelcode == this.code) {
        this.correct = true;
        this.incorrect = false;
      } else {
        this.correct = false;
        this.incorrect = true;
       }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I see you're using animate.css with vue.js. I'd recommend you looking into use Vue transitions https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html and perhaps https://github.com/asika32764/vue2-animate, as you have to keep the state of your animations in the logic of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is have another variable be the control for the animation.  You'd reset that variable after the duration of the animation. I just put 1000 ms in my example.  You may need to debounce a double click if you really want it to be perfect (ie, if they click while the animation is going on, you don't really want to do another animation but maybe you do?).

https://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/zawk41gh/

```
<div id="app" class="card" style="width:18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">

    <div class="alert alert-danger animated" 
    v-bind:class="{ 'shake': runAnimate }" 
    v-if="incorrect">
    Code is incorrect
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-success animated" 
    v-bind:class="{ 'flash': runAnimate }" 
    v-if="correct">
    Correct code entered
    </div>

    <input v-model="modelcode" placeholder="password" class="form-control"> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" @click="checkpwd">check</button>
    correct code is 1234
  </div>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    correct: false,
    incorrect: false,
    code: '1234',
    modelcode: '',
    runAnimate: false
  },
  methods: {
    checkpwd: function(todo){
    this.runAnimate= true;
        if (this.modelcode == this.code) {

        this.correct = true;
        this.incorrect = false;
      } else {
        this.correct = false;
        this.incorrect = true;
       }
       setTimeout(()=> this.runAnimate = false, 1000);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, always have the feeling using setTimeout for these kind of situations is a kind of a hack. But it works.

Comment: You need to delay the resetting of the animation (removing the variable) for the length of the animation.  Nothing wrong with the setTimeout per se.